# Windows dev account cannot as LOB publisher ID

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, lob

My customer add my windows account(xxx@yyy.com) as their LOB publisher. But they are receiving the below error message while adding my account. my userType is Member and no other Roles and other permission. Which type of account address do I need to give? I mean the rolewise. Please guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The email address associated with the Microsoft account that was used to create the **developer account**,so your Windows account(xxx@yyy.com) should be a **paid developer account**. You need to pay for the [Registration fee](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/account-types-locations-and-fees#developer-account-and-app-submission-markets) when you [signup this developer account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account). Please refer to the ***important*** part in document: [Set up the enterprise association](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises#set-up-the-enterprise-association) for more details.

Comment: @DaisyTian MSFT, Hi, I am using the same account for publishing my apps. I hope this should be paid one already. Any my account type is "Company" still it is not allowing to add as LOB publisher

Comment: You may need to ensure that your account is registered for a fee, and not Assign roles as developer to account users.

Comment: @Daisy Tian MSFT, Two questions, 1) The email address role as Manager not developer. Do I need to get the developer role from Global admin since I could not see the option to change it  2) Without fee process completion in the registration does windows allow to submit the app? because I can submit and release app? Please confirm

Comment: The developer account is not the roles developer which was assigned as account users.
If you want to be invited by an enterprise as its developer, and you must register(sign up) a developer account.